# sharable database between devices

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i need a way for a phone to notify all other phones that hold the same application about a change, in my case i am trying to make a hotel booking app , i have managed to create a database and a table called hotels and filled with hotels but the problem is this kind of apps requires a connection between devices, so when i reserve a room in a device , it is also reserved in the other device , i was told i need the work with a server , can anyone give me a good link or something where a newbie like me ( never worked with servers before) to learn a bit thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to create synchronized database is through Firebase realtime database by google. Its very easy to use and not only it will support multiple device at a time but it is also cross platform.

check this.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: thank you so much =) i will look into it